# Why "<<" operator can be inherited but ">>" operator can't?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

Forgive me if it's just a silly question. I'm still new in C++ and this is my practice. I'm trying to create a simple game with Actor Object and Enemy Object that inherit from Unit Object. I put all of stats and overloaded operator that Actor and Enemy share in Unit class. Here's my simplified code for each class file:

**Note:** If this code too long, please just read the error on Actor.cpp and skip all of this. I write all of this because i don't know where's my error begin.

Unit.h

```
#ifndef UNIT_H_INCLUDED
#define UNIT_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Unit{

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Unit&);
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Unit&);

    public:
        Unit(std::string name = "");

        void setName(std::string);

        std::string getName();

        std::string getInfo();

        int attack(Unit&);

    protected:
        std::string name;
};

#endif
```

Unit.cpp

```
#include "Unit.h"

using namespace std;

Unit::Unit(string name){
    this->name = name;
}

void Unit::setName(string name){
    this->name = name;
}

string Unit::getName(){
    return name;
}

string Unit::getInfo(){
    string info;
    info = "Name\t: " + name;
    return info;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Unit& unit){

    output << unit.name << "\n";

    return output;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& input, Unit& unit){

    input >> unit.name;

    return input;
}
```

Actor.h

```
#ifndef ACTOR_H_INCLUDED
#define ACTOR_H_INCLUDED

#include "Unit.h"

class Actor: public Unit{
    public:
        void saveActor();
        void loadActor();
};

#endif
```

Actor.cpp

```
#include "Actor.h"

using namespace std;

void Actor::saveActor(){
    ofstream ofs("actor.txt");
    if(ofs.is_open()){
        ofs << this;    // This work well.
    }
    ofs.close();
}
void Actor::loadActor(){
    ifstream ifs("actor.txt");
    if(ifs.is_open()){
        ifs >> this;    // This is the error.
    }
    ifs.close();
}
```

This code is simplified, my real code includes HP, MP, atk, def, mag, agi with sets and gets for each field which is exactly like name field. That's why i need to overload "<<" and ">>" operators.

My IDE (Visual Studio) said:

> error C2678: binary '>>': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

My question is:

1. Why Actor class can inherit overloaded insertion operator but can't inherit overloaded extraction operator?
2. Is it a good idea to include those standard library in my header files or should I include those in cpp files?

The first question is my problem. The second is just my curiosity, my you all experienced programmer can give me an advice.

*Sorry for my bad language. English is not my main language.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're streaming an `Actor*`

```
ofs << this;
ifs >> this;
```

instead of streaming an `Actor`:

```
ofs << *this;
ifs >> *this;
```

The `ofs` line works because it calls the overload of `operator<<` for printing pointers, not because it's calling your overload on `Unit`.